# PeriodicWorkRequest is not working - why?

Tags: android, performance, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-workmanager

I am using PeriodicWorkRequest with Workmanger to send a local notification every 2 hours from the application. But nothing happens. As soon as I open the application the doWork() method gets called and the notification appears but not when the application is in the background or removed from the recent apps history

```
 Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();


    final PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest
            = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ShowNotificationJob.class, 2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TASK_ID,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, periodicWorkRequest);
```

Comment: on which device are you seeing this behavior? How are you removing the app from recent app history? some OEM are doing a force stop when you swipe out the application from the recent history in the launcher and this stops all the running jobs in JobScheduler by design till the user relaunch the app.

Comment: @pfmaggi I tested on one plus devices(3T, 6T, 7) mainly

Comment: You can repeat your tests with the Android emulator and take a look at this website that explain how to configure a OnePlus device so that it behaves correctly: https://dontkillmyapp.com/oneplus
WorkManager cannot do anything more than a normal application can to bypass these OEM's customizations.

Comment: I am having same issue in oneplus 6t. After Force Stop or Removing app from Tasklist, doWork() call of WorkManager is executed only when app is launched. Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: @agaggi Its still an issue for me on one plus devices, Did you check if your application is optimize by default from system... try disabling that and see the results

Comment: @MRX, yes i tried disabling battery optimization from phone setting, acquiring wakelock, among several other things. The problem is, when target device (oneplus 6/6t in this case) is idle for several minutes, workmanager's periodic work is not executed at all. After banging my head for continuously a week, i found 2 methods which worked for me are, 
1. "send a high priority fcm data message -> then trigger a broadcast -> from broadcast receiver launch a foreground service which perform a given task and then stopself. (launching foreground service directly from fcm service also works). .....

Comment: and 2. Schedule a alarm using setAlarmClock and then launch foreground service from pendingIntent, but the problem with this method is, alarm is cleared on device reboot and BOOT_COMPLETED receiver doesn't works on new oneplus phones and you have no way to set your alarm again after device reboot..

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you use stable version of Workmanager Library
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#declaring_dependencies

**Remove these `constraints` if they are not required**

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Constraints.Builder

> Using these constraints could be the cause not to work in background
>   so make sure you use these constraint as the requirement
>
> And Use ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP instead of ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE - This will not create new object if work manager

```
.setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
```

Final code

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .build();


final PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest
                = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ShowNotificationJob.class, 2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TASK_ID,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWorkRequest);
```

Comment: Only recently I added the constraints. There were none before and the behaviour was same

Comment: ShowNotificationJob post this class here

Comment: I am using the latest version